# Getting unknown character when using Encoding.ASCII.GetString

Tags: c#, client, client-server

I don't post questions often so please bear with me. I'm creating a simple client server in C# for a project. The user types their name and it gets sent to the server where basically the server should respond with an int. Then, the client should take that int and use the method DestinyNumberMeaning which should give out a print statement.

I'm trying to get stringData (which I thought would just be the int from the server) and convert to an int. My issue is that when stringData is storing a character like � which obviously can't be converted to an int. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type your full Name: ");       
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            if (isValid(name))
            {
                name = name.ToLower();
                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name);
                server.Send(data, data.Length);

                data = server.Receive(ref sender);
                stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);
                int num = Convert.ToInt32(stringData);
                DestinyNumberMeaning(num);
                Console.WriteLine("Data: "+stringData);
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Not Valid, Try Again\n");

        }
```

Comment: Without knowing much about your server implementation, this is really hard to help with. It could be an issue with bit endianess if the server is hosted on a different OS than where you're running the client. It could be an issue with the character encoding being different on the client/server. It could also be something else entirely.

Comment: Encoding.ASCII allows only (7-bit) ASCII characters, i.e. mostly only basic letters and numbers. In your case a name like André would be invalid as it contains the non-ASCII character é which would by replaced by surrogate character like a question mark. Usually Encoding.Utf8 or Encoding.Unicode would be used to transmit or store characters.